# Angular2 - 2.4.9 - Custom Validator on reusable component

Tags: angular

I'm trying to create a reusable component that implements Validator. The component needs to check to make sure a number is even. I get an error as follows:

No value accessor for form control with name: '...'

Below is my reusable component:

```
import { Component, Input, forwardRef } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor, FormControl, Validator, NG_VALIDATORS } from '@angular/forms';

const noop = () => {
};

export const CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR: any = {
    provide: [NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, NG_VALIDATORS],
    useExisting: forwardRef(() => EvenValidatorComponent),
    multi: true
};

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'even-validator',
    template: `<div>
<input type="number" [name]="name" [(ngModel)]="customValue" />
</div>`,
    providers: [CUSTOM_INPUT_CONTROL_VALUE_ACCESSOR]
})
export class EvenValidatorComponent implements ControlValueAccessor, Validator {

    private innerValue: number;
    @Input() name: string;

    private onTouchedCallback: () => void = noop;
    private onChangeCallback: (_: any) => void = noop;

    validate(c: FormControl) {
        if (this.innerValue % 2 != 0) {
            return {
                notEvent: { valid: false }
            };
        }

        return null;
    }

    writeValue(value: number) {
        if (value !== this.innerValue) {
            this.innerValue = value;
        }
    }

    registerOnChange(fn: any) {
        this.onChangeCallback = fn;
    }

    registerOnTouched(fn: any) {
        this.onTouchedCallback = fn;
    }
}
```

And my main component:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'sandbox',
    template: `<form>
<even-validator name="evenValidator" [(ngModel)]="numericValue"></even-validator>
</form>`
})
export class SandboxComponent {
    protected  numericValue: number;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the stacktrace

Comment: at _throwError (node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js?v=1490811613984:1737:15) [angular]
    at setUpControl (node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js?v=1490811613984:1650:13) [angular]
    at eval (node_modules/@angular/forms/bundles/forms.umd.js?v=1490811613984:3908:17) [angular]
    at Object.onInvoke (node_modules/@angular/core/bundles/core.umd.js?v=1490811613984:3980:41) [angular]
    at Zone.run (node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:126:43) [angular => angular]
    at node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js:679:57 [angular]

Comment: have you imported the Forms Module or the reactive forms module in your app module ? depending upon what type of form you are using

Comment: Yes I've imported both, no difference.

Comment: But which one are you using i think you are using reactive forms module or data driven forms , but in your template you do not use [formGroup] with forms i feel the code is incomplete